why are my methods triggered by hovering on their links?
I've been scratching my head for a while now. I noticed that some of my entities were disappearing for no apparent reason. Upon investigation, I found out that when I hover over my links, some fetch requests are recorded in the profiler. If those links are tied to delete methods, they get triggered, and upon refresh, the entity in question disappears.
Here's the code for my deleteResource() method:
// Deletes a resource

#[Route('/resource/{id}/delete', name: 'app_resource_delete')]
public function deleteResource(Resource $resource, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{

    if(!$this->getUser()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
    }

    if ($resource->getAuthor() !== $this->getUser() || !in_array('ROLE_MODERATOR', $this->getUser()->getRoles())){
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
    }

    $em->remove($resource);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_resource');
}

and here's an example of what my links look like :
<a class="px-4 py-2 bg-tertiary text-white rounded-lg hover:scale-105 hover:bg-red-600 duration-150 ml-2" href="{{path ('app_ressource_delete', {'id' : ressource.id} )}}">Delete ressource </a>

I expect the deletion to occur only when a user clicks on the corresponding delete link. However, I notice that requests are triggered simply by hovering over certain links, leading to 500 errors in the profiler. When I refresh the page, I find that the deletion has been successfully performed.
I suspect the issue lies in how my links are rendered in the Twig template, but I'm not sure of the best approach to fix this problem. How can I prevent these unexpected requests from occurring when hovering over delete links in my Symfony application?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Honestly i don't even know what to try, dumps don't trigger on refresh so that's a no, removing the hover effect also doesnt do anything, adding an on confirm parameter to the link didn't prevent the deletion, and when i hover on it a bunch of times, this is what my profiler looks like :
screenshot of my profiler
for comparison, here's my profiler when hovering on other links that aren't tied to a method :
other screenshot for comparison

The only thing which could do that is some JavaScript responding to the hover event on those elements and running some script with an AJAX request - which is what the profiler has shown you. Using your browser's Developer Tools to analyse this should lead you to the code which triggered those requests - the Network tool should hopefully give you a stack trace

Thanks a lot for taking to time to answer, i continued my investigation with a friend and found a old reddit post of a guy having a similar problem, turns out to problem was the symfony UX turbo bundle that by default had a pre fetch activated (thanks a lot it would’ve been nicer if it was an option proposed in the webpack.config or if it had at least asked me if i wanted it on) and to fix it i just had to put  in the head.

Your question lacks the IDE you're using as a tag. Also, it could well depend on other plugins you installed and their config.

Oh, btw: Normally, I'd expect an HTTP DELETE on /resource/{id} and not a GET on /resource/{id}/delete.

@UlrichEckhardt Why would the IDE be of any importance?

IDE or wherever else they're "hovering over links", because the code itself doesn't trigger stuff, so something else must be involved.

@UlrichEckhardt hovering over a link in the IDE wouldn't trigger an ajax script to delete a row from the database. We've already established what the cause is anyway, read the preceeding comments

@MohamedAmine Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like an unanswered question - comments are not searchable, and you can't get reputation points for their votes. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Thanks.

I had the same problem and as noted in the comments, it stems from prefetching being enabled on all links. The cause of this is not Symfony or symfony/ux-turbo, but Turbo which since v8 has enabled prefetching by default. As noted in the comments this can be turned off by placing  in the head section of a document.
